# aggregate the reports from different robot testsuites

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I have different test suites in different directories. I use a script to run all these tests in one shot. Now I want to view the report of all these test suites in some aggregated way. What is the best way to aggregate these reports of different test suites(from different directories) in robot?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Robot comes with a tool called "rebot" for combining test results into a single report.

For example, to combine "output1.xml" and "output2.xml" into a single log and report file, you would do something like this:

```
rebot output1.xml output2.xml
```

For more information see [Using rebot tool](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-rebot) in the [robot user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. I solved it.
For further elaboration

By default, output xml is named as *output.xml* . To change it to some other name as you mentioned

```
pybot  --output output1.xml <test_suite>
```

then we can use rebot as

```
rebot --outputdir <directory-you-want-to-have-output-reports> --output <aggregated_xml_name: eg: final_output.xml> output1.xml output2.xml .....
```