# Robot File Automation testing

Tags: robotframework

I am running some test case using robot framework , I want to see the consolidated report after firing the test cases , let's say , 5 files got fired and two of them got failed  , I should get a report which clearly says me 3/5 got passed.

Comment: please spend some time reading the robot framework documentation, this is a pretty simple and well known aspect.

Comment: search for information about "rebot", a tool that comes with robot which can be used to combine test results from multiple runs.

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing a testcase, report logs are being generated afterwards. By default the logs are going to be in the same folder where your testcases are, under the name `log.html`. Find the corresponnding example here: https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/webdemo#rst-header-generated-results

And this is how the result logs looks like. This test suite contains 3 individual tests:

http://robotframework.bitbucket.org/WebDemo/log.html

Comment: Thanks Richard ,but i was asking like i am running multiple test suites all from different files and want to see the consolidated output.

Comment: i am sorry then, can you please provide an example how and what are you executing to be able to help you?

Comment: Do you need to merge five different reports? You should look into rebot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519277/aggregate-the-reports-from-different-robot-testsuites